# Slow load times

Tags: support, android-app

I am using the new Nexus 7 running Android 4.3 and I am getting really long load times especially when opening questions and in general. I can browse the stack exchange sites so much faster just in chrome.

To be clear, the page template loads fast and just waiting for the question data.

Is this a common experience?

Comment: _"the page template loads fast"_ that's because it's set up by the application, not the site. To answer your question: you're network must be slow.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I know why the template loads fast but content is slow and was only clarifying what is being slow. Compared to just browsing StackExchange sites in chrome, the app is much much slower and sometimes doesn't even load the question.

Comment: I am getting almost similar load times from both the browser and the app.

Comment: possibly realated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200065/stack-exchange-app-extremely-slow-with-adblock-plus-enabled

Comment: @StevenV Yeeeepp, Just disabled Adblock and it works like a charm!

Comment: @MLM may want to comment on that thread as well that you're able to reproduce this. Odd behavior for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steven V](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215013/steven-v) just commented on the original post with [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200065/stack-exchange-app-extremely-slow-with-adblock-plus-enabled) which talks about Ad-block causing the app to be slow.

I just disabled the adblock filtering and it works like a charm.

This is the only app that I have a problem with ad-block.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly why your load times are slow.  We have thought a lot about how to make load times faster on mobile but there are things that are outside of our control (providers, reception, etc).  In our testing the mobile app is either on par with load times from the mobile version of the site or significantly faster.