# SE Android App is extremely slow with AdBlock Plus enabled

Tags: bug, android-app

I've toyed with this on my tablet, and I've noticed that the application is incredibly slow when AdBlock Plus is enabled on my mobile device.

It just sits there at "Loading your user information...".  There aren't any error dialogs as best as I can tell.  If I navigate away to another window, sometimes another action is able to get through, but I'm reluctant to call that "consistent" behavior.

I can access http://api.stackexchange.com and http://mobile.stackexchange.com on my tablet just fine. To my understanding, there aren't any firewalls enabled on the tablet. There aren't any firewalls on my router that would restrict me from hitting those sites.

It seems like a bug - all of my other applications work just fine with ABP enabled.

Comment: Are you sure your connection just isn't slow?

Comment: 40Mb line.  No, my connection *isn't* slow.  And, the app works swimmingly without it enabled.

Comment: Just because your peak bandwidth is 40Mbps doesn't mean your _connection_ is 40Mbps. With that logic, my measly 8Mbps Wi-Fi speed should be 150! And my gigabit Ethernet should be 1Gbps!

Comment: Be that as it may, my connection is not the culprit here.  Something else is going on.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the official Stack Exchange app.  The website is perfectly responsive with ABP enabled.

Comment: It sounds like there's something else going on here. Do you have any firewalls installed? Can you reach https://api.stackexchange.com and https://mobile.stackexchange.com on your phone's browser?

Comment: I can access both sites on my tablet just fine.  To my understanding, there aren't any firewalls enabled on the tablet.  There aren't any firewalls on my router that would restrict me from hitting those sites.

Comment: I'll ask the seemingly dumb question, have you disabled ABP and experienced this behavior?

Comment: No, it works just fine with ABP disabled.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and fixed by disabling: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196825/slow-load-times/ - This is also the only app I have that has issues with ad block.

Comment: I know it's an old bug report, but what's your device model and Android version? Also, was your device rooted? It might have something to do with proxy

Comment: I confirm having the same problem with AdAway to change my host file on a rooted Android device. It would be great to know what to white-list in order to avoid those issues. I've measured over 1 min 20s of loading time when using AdAway, while it's below 5s without.